# MySQL returns Latin characters when search for English

Tags: sql, laravel, collation

`MedicalTerms::where('term','like','%hce%')->get();`

Above Laravel command generates this sql `SELECT * FROM medical_terms WHERE term like '%hce%'`
and it returns the result below. Why does `c` considers as `ç` in sql?
Indeed this query should return 0 records.

[image]

Comment: The problem is collation. I changed `utf8mb4_general_ci` to `utf8mb4_bin` the it hits the correct record but becomes case sensitive. Except that I didn't see any harm changing the collation.

Answer (score 0):

one solution is define new column **language**

and in your query add additional condition

```
MedicalTerms::where('term','like','%hce%')->where('language',$request->language)->get();
```

hopefully that is help you